# If $\nabla u \parallel n$ then $|\nabla u(x_0)|=|\nabla u(x_0)\cdot n|,\;\;\;x_0\in\partial\Omega$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ an open and bounded set, with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. If $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ then $\nabla u \parallel n$ where $n$ is the unit normal vector on $\partial\Omega$. My question is: Why
$$|\nabla u(x_0)|=|\nabla u(x_0)\cdot n|,\;\;\;x_0\in\partial\Omega\;\;?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$
|\nabla u(x_0)\cdot {\bf n}| = |\nabla u(x_0)| |{\bf n}| |\cos\theta|
$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla u(x_0)$ and ${\bf n}$